# Algorithm for finding the appropriate rotating frame Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hamiltonian

**Context**

Consider an $N$-level Hamiltonian with energies $\omega_1...\omega_N$ with coupling drives at frequencies $f_{i,j}$ which couple the $i$ and $j$-th levels (not necessarily resonantly, so $f_{i,j} \neq \omega_j - \omega_i$).

This Hamiltonian looks something like

$$H = \sum_{i}^{N} \omega_i \vert i\rangle \langle i \vert + \sum_{i,j} \Omega_{i,j}\cos(f_{i,j} t) \vert i\rangle \langle j \vert + h.c.$$
Or as a matrix

$$H= \begin{bmatrix} 
    \omega_1 & \Omega_{1,2}\cos(f_{1,2} t) & \Omega_{1,3}\cos(f_{1,3} t) & \dots\\
\Omega^*_{1,2}\cos(f_{1,2} t)& \omega_2& \Omega_{2,3}\cos(f_{2,3} t) & \dots \\
    \Omega_{1,3}^*\cos(f_{1,2} t) & \Omega^*_{2,3}\cos(f_{2,3} t)&\omega_3 & \dots\\
    \vdots & \vdots &\vdots  & \ddots
    \end{bmatrix}$$

The rotating wave approximate to $H$, denoted $H_{RWA}$ would involve first replacing the $\cos(f_{i,j} t)$ terms with $e^{i f_{i,j} t}$

$$H\approx \tilde{H} = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \omega_1 & \Omega_{1,2}e^{if_{1,2} t} & \Omega_{1,3}e^{if_{1,3} t}& \dots\\
\Omega^*_{1,2}e^{-if_{1,2} t}& \omega_2& \Omega_{2,3}e^{if_{2,3} t} & \dots \\
    \Omega_{1,3}^*e^{-if_{1,2} t} & \Omega^*_{2,3}e^{-if_{2,3} t}&\omega_3 & \dots\\
    \vdots & \vdots &\vdots  & \ddots
    \end{bmatrix}$$

The second step, which actually involves no approximation and is for convenience, is to come up with an appropriate unitary matrix $U$ which gets rid of all (or almost all?) time dependence with

$$H_{RWA}= U^{\dagger} \tilde{H}U + i(\partial_t U^{\dagger}) U$$

**Question**

**Is there an algorithm for going through the frequencies appearing in the Hamiltonian $H$ and coming up with the appropriate rotating frame transform $U$ and obtain $H_{RWA}$ from $H, \tilde{H}$?**

It is easy enough to do the RWA when you have two levels, but it is unclear to me how to do it systematically for larger $N$.

Comment: You're confusing two separate concepts: 1) the rotating frame and 2) the rotating wave approximation. Your $U$ is not a "rotating wave transform" (I've never heard that term before). Rather, it's just a change of frame.

Comment: @DanielSank thank you. Perhaps I used the wrong term, but is it not true that you have two ingredients: replace the real sinusoid with one one complex exponential, then a unitary transform to get rid of the time dep. My question is about getting $U$ properly

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to your question is the following.
Consider a unitary transformation of the form
$$
U(t) = \text{diag}\left(e^{ix_1t},\,e^{ix_2t},\, ... \right),
$$
the Hamiltonian, written in the rotating frame, is $U^{\dagger}(t) H U(t) + iU^{\dagger}(t)\partial_t U(t)$. A diagonal element at position $i$ is time independent and given by $\omega_i-x_i$; while an off-diagonal element at position $ij$ (with $j>i$) is time dependent, and it reads
$$
\Omega_{ij} e^{i(f_{ij} - x_i + x_j)t}.
$$
In order to make all of these terms time independent, we get a set of equation of the form
$$
x_i - x_j = f_{ij}.
$$

This is a set of (at most) $N(N-1)/2$ equations with only $N$ variables, which means that it can't be solved in general. However, under specific circumstances, it can be solved.
In fact notice that if one of the couplings $\Omega_{ij}$ vanishes, then we have one less equation to solve, so the number of independent equations is $N(N-1)/2 - n$, where $n$ is the number of couplings that are set to 0.

For example, if $N=2$, then $N(N-1)/2 = 1$ and we have one equation and two variables: $x_1 - x_2 = f_{12}$, which has infinite solutions, for example $x_1 = f_{12}$ and $x_2=0$.
Another example is the case $N=3$ with, say, $\Omega_{12}=0$. In this case, the equation $x_1-x_2=f_{12}$ doesn't hold and we just get
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
x_1 - x_3 = f_{13} \\
x_2 - x_3 = f_{23}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which has infinite solutions, for example $x_3=0$, $x_2 = f_{23}$ and $x_1 = f_{13}$.

Of course this is not the most general answer to your question, but at least it paves the way to a first attempt of solution.
Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you! There was a typo in my equation, the time derivative for $U$ was in the wrong place, which changes a few of the signs. Anyways, so would you think that in general it should not be possible to find a $U$ which gets rid of all time dep of the RWA form, even if you allow for off diagonal terms?

Comment: Or is there some theorem that RWA Hamiltonians of the form in my question $\tilde{H}$ can always be written in a time dep form after a unitary transformation?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what happens when allowing off diagonal terms in $U(t)$. However the trick shown here can be used in some of the most relevant real life situations.